# Problems setting style tag to a div

Tags: javascript

I am creating something with JS and I cannot seem to add the style tag to a div that I created via javascript (I am not making a class for css for a reason do not suggest it) here is my code

```
function createForm()
{
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container-fluid");
    var formElement = document.createElement("form");
    var inputName = document.createElement("input");
    var inputEvent = document.createElement("input");
    var inputTime = document.createElement("input");
    var sendWithTimer = document.createElement("input");
    var sendWithoutTimer = document.createElement("input");
    var divContainer = document.createElement("div");
    formElement.className = "form";
    divContainer.className = "enforce-styles";
    inputName.className = "name";
    inputEvent.className = "event";
    inputTime.className = "time";
    sendWithTimer.className = "sendWithTimer";
    sendWithoutTimer.className = "sendWithoutTimer";
    inputName.setAttribute('type', "text");
    inputEvent.setAttribute('type', "text");
    inputTime.setAttribute('type', "text");
    inputName.setAttribute('placeholder', "Name");
    inputEvent.setAttribute('placeholder', "Event");
    inputTime.setAttribute('placeholder', "Time");
    sendWithTimer.setAttribute('type', "button");
    sendWithoutTimer.setAttribute('type', "button");
    sendWithTimer.setAttribute('value', "Timer");
    sendWithoutTimer.setAttribute('value', "No timer");
    formElement.appendChild(inputName);
    formElement.appendChild(inputEvent);
    formElement.appendChild(inputTime);
    divContainer.appendChild(sendWithTimer);
    divContainer.appendChild(sendWithoutTimer);
    for (var formElementStyles = 0; formElementStyles < formElement.length; formElementStyles++)
    {
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.display = "-webkit-flex";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.display = "flex";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.webkitFlexDirection = "column";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.flexDirection = "column";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.position = "relative";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.top = 0;
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.left = 40 + "%";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.padding = 0.6 + "em";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.margin = 1 + "em";
    }
    for (var divContainerStyles = 0; divContainerStyles < divContainer.length; divContainerStyles++)
    {
        divContainer[divContainerStyles].style.display = "-webkit-flex";
        divContainer[divContainerStyles].style.display = "flex";
        divContainer[divContainerStyles].style.webkitFlexDirection = "column";
        divContainer[divContainerStyles].style.flexDirection = "column";
        divContainer[divContainerStyles].style.position = "relative";
        divContainer[divContainerStyles].style.top = 0;
        divContainer[divContainerStyles].style.left = 40 + "%";
        divContainer[divContainerStyles].style.padding = 0.6 + "em";
        divContainer[divContainerStyles].style.margin = 1 + "em";
        divContainer[divContainerStyles].style.height = 10 + "em";
    }
    container[0].appendChild(formElement);
    container[0].appendChild(divContainer);
}
```

I cannot seem to get the second for loop to place the style tags. The div just appears with nothing but a class name which was set above. But I cannot get the styles on there. The styles are for two buttons inside a form I am inserting into a clients website. How can I get this to work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about divContainer[divContainerStyles].setAttribute('style', <your styles>)

Comment: That'll work please post that in an answer and so I can accept it

Comment: Just a thought: you're probably much better just using JS to set classes to DOM elements and actually letting CSS set the styles. That would avoid the soupy code you got there and adheres to a good principle of separation of concerns in web development.

Comment: Phillip as I said I am working on a clients website. I have my reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not apply the style to the input fields, because `divContainer.length` does not exist, neither does `divContainer[divContainerStyles]`. divContainer is an div Object and has no length attribute (as opposed to the form element, which does have a length attribute) so that's why it never gets into the second loop.

Your code produces the following error: https://jsfiddle.net/tdbju0ud/

Instead, you should check for the length of divContainer.childNodes and apply the styles to those.

```
for (var divContainerStyles = 0; divContainerStyles < divContainer.childNodes.length; divContainerStyles++)
{
    divContainer.childNodes[divContainerStyles].style.display = "-webkit-flex";
    ...
}
```

A working test in: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvq6hvxd/

Comment: [Error] - create-form.js:50 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: The code in fiddle works for you? if so, then the error has to come from somewhere else in your code. Make sure all references inside the second loop include the `childNodes` bit and any possible typos. If you post more code I can check further.

Comment: Error - Length of divContainer undefined

Comment: My post may have been confusing. The fiddle that works is the second one => https://jsfiddle.net/Lvq6hvxd/ The first one was just to show you the reason for the error in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

This will work- `divContainer[divContainerStyles].setAttribute('style', <your styles>)`

Answer (score 0):

Use childNodes to get the child elements of the div container. 
 like

```
var nodes = divContainer.childNodes
```

Find out the length of this nodes array object to find out the child elements count of the div.

Here is the corrected code :

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container-fluid");
    var formElement = document.createElement("form");
    var inputName = document.createElement("input");
    var inputEvent = document.createElement("input");
    var inputTime = document.createElement("input");
    var sendWithTimer = document.createElement("input");
    var sendWithoutTimer = document.createElement("input");
    var divContainer = document.createElement("div");
    formElement.className = "form";
    divContainer.className = "enforce-styles";
    inputName.className = "name";
    inputEvent.className = "event";
    inputTime.className = "time";
    sendWithTimer.className = "sendWithTimer";
    sendWithoutTimer.className = "sendWithoutTimer";
    inputName.setAttribute('type', "text");
    inputEvent.setAttribute('type', "text");
    inputTime.setAttribute('type', "text");
    inputName.setAttribute('placeholder', "Name");
    inputEvent.setAttribute('placeholder', "Event");
    inputTime.setAttribute('placeholder', "Time");
    sendWithTimer.setAttribute('type', "button");
    sendWithoutTimer.setAttribute('type', "button");
    sendWithTimer.setAttribute('value', "Timer");
    sendWithoutTimer.setAttribute('value', "No timer");
    formElement.appendChild(inputName);
    formElement.appendChild(inputEvent);
    formElement.appendChild(inputTime);
    divContainer.appendChild(sendWithTimer);
    divContainer.appendChild(sendWithoutTimer);
    for (var formElementStyles = 0; formElementStyles < formElement.length; formElementStyles++) {
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.display = "-webkit-flex";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.display = "flex";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.webkitFlexDirection = "column";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.flexDirection = "column";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.position = "relative";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.top = 0;
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.left = 40 + "%";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.padding = 0.6 + "em";
        formElement[formElementStyles].style.margin = 1 + "em";
    }
var divChildNodes = divContainer.childNodes; 
    for (var divContainerStyles = 0; divContainerStyles < divChildNodes.length; divContainerStyles++) {
        divChildNodes[divContainerStyles].style.display = "-webkit-flex";
        divChildNodes[divContainerStyles].style.display = "flex";
        divChildNodes[divContainerStyles].style.webkitFlexDirection = "column";
        divChildNodes[divContainerStyles].style.flexDirection = "column";
        divChildNodes[divContainerStyles].style.position = "relative";
        divChildNodes[divContainerStyles].style.top = 0;
        divChildNodes[divContainerStyles].style.left = 40 + "%";
        divChildNodes[divContainerStyles].style.padding = 0.6 + "em";
        divChildNodes[divContainerStyles].style.margin = 1 + "em";
        divChildNodes[divContainerStyles].style.height = 10 + "em";
    }
    container[0].appendChild(formElement);
    container[0].appendChild(divContainer);
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined I will just make ids and style them that way

Comment: what browser are u using? It worked fine for me actually.